# Start chart from threshold

Tags: highcharts

Current implementation:

[image]

Desired implementation:

[image]

If you look carefully there is a vertical line connecting  threshold with the first point of my displayed chart. Any ideas how to implement it ? What I thought was to get the threshold price (got it)and find a way to insert it a starting point, but I struggle a bit (since i use unix timestamp).Thanks in advance !

I parse the data from Monday to Friday, but I only display Intraday's data (let's say I am o Friday now). So the threshold will be the closing price from Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Inserting a starting point seems to be the best solution for that. You can do it as below:

```
const threshold = 10;
const data = [
    [20, 11],
    ...
];

data.unshift([data[0][0], threshold]);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        threshold,
        data
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7ynzhmuv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.threshold